# Trying to echo ONLY if the users rank in database is = to 2

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Trying to echo ONLY if the users rank in database is = to 2

So it echos it even if its rank is 0 and I don't know why. Here is my code.

```
    <?php
        $query299 = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . "'";
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query299);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $row2 = $stmt2->fetch();
        if($row2['rank'] = 2) {
            echo '
                <li>
                    <a href="admin.php">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                    <span>Admin</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            ';
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$row2['rank'] = 2` this is assignment not compare change `$row2['rank'] = =2`

Comment: A bit Change in my above comment `$row2['rank'] ==2`

Comment: Peoples are mad. asking question, taking answers, but not interested in marking. WTF is going on. Bad laziness

Comment: I am deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this statement here,

```
if($row2['rank'] = 2) { ...
                 ^ you're doing assignment, not comparison
```

It should be,

```
if($row2['rank'] == 2) {
```

Comment: @RyanSeecrest Glad I could help. Cheers! ;-) You've been given answers here, please consider marking the correct answer as *accepted answer*. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)